# Bottom layout guide prevents interaction with the uitoolbar which is exchanged with the uitabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I am trying to make it possible to exchange the tab bar with the tool bar on iOS when the UITableView enters the editing mode.
However, when I set the

```
func updateBottomBar() {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = isInEditMode
    actionToolBar.isHidden = !isInEditMode
}
```

, everything displays correct, however I can not interact with the toolbar. It seems like it is under the bottom layout guide, and the touches cant pass through. I tried bumping the toolbar.layer.zposition to 100, didnt work.

**Note:** if I programatically reposition the ToolBar to be a little bit higher, then exactly the portion of the ToolBar which is above the top of now hidden TabBar will be okay to interact with. Say i put the ToolBar 20points higher, then the 20 top points of the ToolBar allow me to press the buttons, and the bottom part doesn't allow.

I have:

- extended edges under bottom bar disabled
- Hides bottom bar on push disabled
- user interaction enabled

right now. Changing those didn't give any success.

[image: ui]

[image: ui]

[image: constraints]

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue could be your `userInteraction` of your custom tabbar being set to false.

You can do that directly in the your storyboard by opening the attribute inspector on your ActionToolBar

Also, to confirm you don't have any invisible view on top of your custom toolbar, you can use debug the view hierarchy when running on your simulator:

[image]

Comment: Same for the buttons inside your view?

Comment: yeah, I have just added a note: if I programatically reposition the ToolBar to be a little bit higher, then exactly the portion of the ToolBar which is above the top of now hidden TabBar will be okay to interact with.

Comment: also, for your addition, here is the stack view, it is exactly on the top:
https://imgur.com/a/W3Cl3Si

Comment: tabbar doesnt have "isEnabled" property

Comment: Oops yeah sorry, I meant on the tabbaritems. But it certainly not that. I'm trying to reproduce your bug on my side :)

Comment: any success? :)